# command is throwing error in unix

Tags: shell

We have executed below command and getting some error.

```
k="";while read r;do [ "$k" != "" ] ="$k|";k="$k^$r\$";done<1;awk -v "KEY=$k" -v "CB=CB" -v "CSA=CSA" "BEGIN{FS=\"|\";OFS=\"|\"}{if (\$2 ~ KEY){print \$0>CB}else{print \$0>CSA}}" abc
```

Error:

```
bash: line 1: [: missing `]'
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why one line?  Written more sanely, your code is:

```
k=""
while read r
do
    [ "$k" != "" ] ="$k|"
    k="$k^$r\$"
done <1

awk -v "KEY=$k" -v "CB=CB" -v "CSA=CSA" \
    'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"}{if ($2 ~ KEY){print $0>CB}else{print $0>CSA}}' abc
```

The problem is with the `test` command:

```
[ "$k" != "" ] ="$k|"
```

The last argument to the command is `="$k|"`, but `[` requires the last argument to be `]`.

The `awk` program was simplified by using single quotes around the program — you no longer needs any backslashes.

The `<1` redirection is a little odd too; it reads from a file called `1`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler... Can please correct the command as i am not getting your point exactly..

Comment: @vishal, can you explain what you're trying to do with `[ "$k" != "" ] ="$k|"` ?

Comment: Since it is very, very far from clear what you are trying to do, I can't help you.  Maybe you had in mind `[ "$k" != "" ] && k="$k|"` for the condition line; this would add a pipe `|` after the string if it is not empty, before adding a caret `^`, the line that was read, and a dollar `$`.  But it isn't clear what you're after; that's a lot of separator characters.